# WCF svc unregistered from iis

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-7.5

I am getting a 404 when ever I try open a .svc file in iis 7.5, my system.serviceModel from web config is below:

```
<system.serviceModel>

    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true. Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="Gsfa.Gsfbs.Integration.Services.MemberIntegrationService">
        <endpoint address="https://gsfdevmatthewc/MemberIntegrationService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBinding" contract="Gsfa.Gsfbs.Integration.Contracts.IMemberIntegrationService" />
      </service>
    </services>


  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: And what address are you using. The address you specified in the endpoint is not used. The address of your hosting site matters.

Comment: Ok I have done some more digging and it apears that .svc has dropped out of the Handler Mappings in iis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it I needed to re-register everything in iis.

1. Open cmd as administrator
2. Type the following:

   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
3. Your Done.